# Is JSON deserialization in Apex case sensitive?

Tags: apex, json, deserialize

If I have to deserialize a response like this:

```
{ "Property1" : "value", "Property2" : "value2" }
```

Do I have to respect the case of the property names? I would rather use camel case to stick with our Apex naming conventions, e.g:

```
class Response {
    String property1;
    String property2;
}

Response res = (Response)JSON.deserialize(myJson, Response.class);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This doesn't matter when you're doing *typed* deserialization, but it will be an issue if you do *untyped* deserialization because any `Map<String, Object>` that you pull out will necessarily have case-sensitive keys.

#### Case insensitive

`JSON.deserialize(jsonString, SpecificType.class)`
`JSON.deserializeStrict(jsonString, SpecificType.class)`

#### Case Sensitive

`JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonString)`

Comment: Worth also noting that `JSON.deserializeStrict` is also case insensitive for keys. Values may, of course, be case sensitive depending on their type and how they are used in the code.

Comment: I suppose that `JSONParser` is also case-insensitive (due to string comparison being case-insensitive by default), but if you're using `JSONParser` over one of the `JSON.deserialize*` methods you're either doing something wrong or you already know exactly what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to respect the case of the properties in the JSON string you are deserializing.

JSON deserialization in Apex is not case sensitive.

The above code will work fine.